# Conformal welding and Jordan loop consequences?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, dimension-theory, quasiconformal, conformal-maps, jordan-curves

In the similar context as [Conformal welding of rectifiable curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357519/conformal-welding-of-rectifiable-curves)

> In classical conformal welding theory, we start with a homeomorphism $h$ of the unit circle and try to find a Jordan domain $D$ together with two conformal isomorphisms $f_1 \colon \mathbb D \to D$ and $f_2 \colon \hat{\mathbb C} \backslash \overline{\mathbb D} \to \hat{\mathbb C} \backslash \overline{D}$.
> such that $h|_{S^1} = f_1^{-1} \circ f_2$. The existence of these two maps are guaranteed if $h$ is a quasisymmetric homeomorphism, and the uniqueness follows from uniqueness of complex dilatation.

I showed existence of conformal welding for a particular non-quasisymmetric map $h$ using a condition called Lehto condition (see ["Random Conformal Weldings"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1003#:%7E:text=We%20construct%20a%20conformally%20invariant,homeomorphisms%20of%20the%20unit%20circle.) for the setting).

This resulted in the above mentioned conformal maps and a Jordan loop $\Gamma=\partial D$.

> What can we try to prove about $\Gamma$ using the particular properties of $h$? For example, can we prove any multifractal spectrum questions about $\Gamma$?

I understand this question is a bit open-ended but I am not familiar with the literature. Other than that there is unique correspondence in the quasisymmetric setting, I don't know whether the quasisymmetric welding maps can be used to be compute properties about the resulting Jordan loop $\Gamma$.

For example, I don't know if the answer is trivially no  "no very little can be inferred" or trivially yes "yes many properties can be inferred eg. see work on...".

Bishop in the work "Conformal welding and Koebe's theorem", manages to build some approximations to the loop $\Gamma$ but I am not sure what information is preserved in the limit.

Comment: There exist $h$ for which the corresponding curve $\Gamma$ is not unique, not even up to Mobius transformation. For instance, take $h$ to be log-singular as in the paper of Bishop that you mention. In this case, your question seems ill defined.

Comment: On the other hand, if your $h$ is 'nicer', then usually one deduces properties of $\Gamma$ by construction. For example, if $h$ is quasisymmetric, then the proof that there exists a corresponding $\Gamma$ shows that $\Gamma$ has to be a quasicircle. For your particular $h$, since you use Lehto's condition, you should be able to deduce that $\Gamma$ is the boundary of a Holder domain, as in the "Random Conformal Weldings" paper that you mentioned.

Comment: Lastly, did you look at Vainio's paper :J. V. Vainio : Conditions for the possibility of conformal sewing. Ann. Acad.Sci. Fenn. Ser. A I Math. Dissertationes, (53):43, 1985 ?
I was not able to find it, but it might contain some information about what properties of $\Gamma$ can be deduced in the case where $h$ satisfies the Lehto condition.

Comment: thank you for the references.